# Email-to-Case & Assignment Rules - Which Address Received the Email?

Tags: email, case

I received an email from Client@Example.com.

In conjunction with the Email-to-Case function, our Assignment Rules and Round-Robin Apex code dictate that when email is sent to our company using MyMailQueue@myCompany.com, create a case and assign that case to a queue called MyMailQueue.

Other than stepping through the assignment rules and Apex code, is there another way to see that the case was created because mail was sent to the address above?

In other words, I'm looking for a way to see that the email address above is definitely the one that was used because we use several different email addresses in Email-to-Case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Off the top of my head, three solutions come to mind - all point and click

In Email to Case setup, do one of the following:

1. Use different record types for each inbound email2case address. Display record type on Case page layout
2. Use different Case Origin values: `Email-A, Email-B, etc`. Display on page layout
3. Create a Task with a different status `Completed Email2Case-A, Completed Email2Case-B, etc`. Inspect Activity History list

Email2Case always creates a new Case if there's no threadId. The above should allow identification of which path was taken

Comment: Cropredy, those are excellent suggestions moving forward, and I will use them, but I need a way to look back at a situation that has already happened. Similar to how an IT worker could check an Exchange Mail server and see what time mail was sent, who it was sent from, who it was sent to etc. I know Salesforce personnel have this info because Email-to-Case uses their mail servers. I'd just like to know if they make this detailed information available to us.

Comment: @Izzy can you look at the SFDC email logs and match on time?  Logs go back 6 months